# Ruby on Rails: Keep Bootstrap Modal open after Postback when error occurs in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise to handle my authentication needs. The Sign up and Login Devise form is being presented in a Bootstrap 3 modal. When an error occurs on submit I would like to keep this modal open after the page posts back. right now the modal disappears.

My scenario I want to address is, when an error occurs on submit how can I keep the modal open to display the error message after the post back?

I was wondering what the best way of doing this. Code is below.

#### Home View - Sign up Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mod_SignUp">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div id="user" class="registration-modal-body small-top-spacer">
            <div class="modal-header">
              #Devise error label goes here#
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Step 1 - Sign Up</h3>
            </div>
                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='row small-topdown-spacer'>
                            <label id="lbl_error_email" class='label label-danger'></label>
                        </div>
                        <%= f.email_field :email, :id => 'txt_email', :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'E-mail'%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="lbl_error_password" class="label label-danger small-topdown-spacer"></label>
                        <%= f.password_field :password, :id => 'txt_password', :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Password' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label id="lbl_error_password_confirmation" class="label label-danger small-topdown-spacer"></label>
                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :id => 'txt_confirm_password', :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Confirm Password' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
<%= f.submit :Submit, :id => 'btn_Next', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>

           $('#btn_SignUp').click(function () {
            $('#mod_SignUp').modal();
        });
```

#### Devise Sign up Controller Method

```
 # POST /resource
```

def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

```
resource_saved = resource.save
yield resource if block_given?
if resource_saved
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

end

#### Routes

```
root to: 'home#index'

 devise_for :users
 as :user do
    post 'home', to: 'registrations#create'
 end

 get "home/index"
 get 'home/get_email' => 'home#get_email'
 get "home/show" => "home#show"
 get "profile/new" => "profile#new"
 get "home/login" => "home#login"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Ajax to achieve this. If you already has override `Devise::RegistrationsController`, you could simply modify the `respond_to` method :

**Code Ruby**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :html, :json
end
```

This will allow you to sign up for example using either HTML or JSON.

**Code Haml**

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { id: "register-form" }) do |f|
/ ... code ...
/ ... code ...
  = f.submit :Submit
```

Then in your Javascript/CoffeeScript, you can simply make an Ajax request :

**Code CoffeeScript**

```
$("#register-form").on 'submit', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $.ajax
    type: "POST"
    url: $(@).attr('action')
    data: $(@).serializeArray()
    dataType: "json"
    beforeSend: =>
      $(@).find('.form-error').remove()
    success: (user) =>
      # If saved, will here return the saved user
    error: (xhr) ->
      errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors
      # If any errors, "errors" will contains ActiveRecord validations errors
      console.log errors # JSON object containing errors
```

Comment: +1 for the Coffee Script. Thanks. So, what this code does is, if error then post the error instead of submitting?

Comment: In any case, this will post your form. If there's errors, Devise will return `:unprocessable_entity` which will trigger the error callback with ActiveRecord errors validation (password does not match...etc...). From there, you can just loop on the `errors` and display them onto the form. For the success part, I generally simply do a simple redirect `window.location.replace("/")` as Im using Devise confirmable which will display then the flash notice `You will receive an email...` on `root_path`

Comment: @ElKey I haven't gotten around to trying your solution yet. I will mark your post as the answer once I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: How do you override the registration controller please ? Because I did your way but I still have the same problem.